# Introducing Generic Review Tool

Tags: discussion, reviewing, userscript

Generic Review Tool is a small script designed to detect review tasks on CGCC, and open them in a new tab. It is similar in function to [Review Stalker Reloaded](https://stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded-a-cross-site-dashboard-for-reviews), probably the most widely used script for this purpose, but with much simpler functionality. RSR is no longer maintained and has quite a few bugs, which is what prompted this script.

#### Details

Generic Review Tool is quite simple to use; simply open the [`/review`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review) page. If your browser supports it, pinning that tab is a good idea since it will just sit in the background. The script will check periodically for new review tasks, and if it finds any they will be opened in new tabs.

By default, GRT will check for new tasks every 40 seconds. This is faster than the defaults for other scripts, because GRT has **much lower overhead**. Rather than reloading the whole page, which may involve downloading CSS and images, considerable DOM manipulation, and running other scripts, GRT just fetches the needed information asynchronously.

The time between each check can be customized, by editing the script. Changing the `UPDATE_INTERVAL` to the desired number of milliseconds is all that is required. I wouldn't recommend anything lower than 20 seconds (although 10 seconds should *technically* work).

#### Download

Generic Review Tool is a user script, meaning that it requires Greasemonkey (Firefox or browsers that support Firefox extensions) or Tampermonkey (Chrome or browsers that support Chrome extensions) to be installed.

**[Generic Review Tool 1.0.1](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/generic-review-tool.user.js)**